# What will happen?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am an event,
>       relations I set.
>       Make most to fret,
>       threat because they get.
>
> I sound like evil,
>       but actually I'm not.
>       Maybe as a concept,
>       but it is not my fault.
>
> I sound like fact,
>       reality, exact.
>       Nothing do I have
>       to do with all that.
>
> Honor and villainy,
>       beauty' n' unsightly,
>       a great example of me
>       contains of these the three.
>
> My brother who has two,
>       is way more known, too.
>       Through me he who goes through,
>       does not need know kung fu.

Hint (for the brother):

> Glove

Hint 2:

> Winner takes all (obviously)

Comment: Any chance of a hint? I'm still thinking about this one.

Comment: I think this hint is strong enough to guide, but unclear enough to steal the achievement of success. I'll be adding more every few days.

Comment: I knew there was a reason I kept this tab open for so many weeks :-) Nice puzzle.

Comment: So glad you liked it, I really enjoyed making it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but could you be

> a [TRUEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truel), or duel between three people, as in the [famous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/295/5373).

*I am an event,

    relations I set.

    Make most to fret,

    threat because they get.*

> A duel/truel is (was) an event due to some bad relations between two/three people. In olden times, a threat might easily result in such an event.

*I sound like evil,

    but actually I'm not.

    Maybe as a concept,

    but it is not my fault.*

> The word sounds like CRUEL, which is evil. The concept of fighting a duel/truel is a bad thing, but it's the fault of the people doing it (or the society encouraging it) rather than the duel/truel itself.

*I sound like fact,

    reality, exact.

    Nothing do I have

    to do with all that.*

> The word truel also sounds like TRUE, but they're completely unrelated in meaning.

*Honor and villainy,

    beauty' n' unsightly,

    a great example of me

    contains of these the three.*

> This is a reference to one of the most famous truels in cinema, [*The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly).

*My brother who has two,

    is way more known, too.

    Through me he who goes through,

    does not need know kung fu.*

> Duels with two people are better known than truels with three. Maybe, given Hint 1, this might be something about boxing or martial arts, which could be seen as a sort of (usually friendly) 'duel'.

Comment: You are really close. It is interesting to see the way you explained the parts that are off. What you have found is actually rot13(gur "oebgure jub unf gjb" vgfrys). So just take an extra step, and i'm sure even the missing points will become clear! And actually, the missing points now become hints for you.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis If my answer is the brother, then maybe the actual answer is rot13(fhvpvqr)?

Comment: ahh no. much closer than that. My sources say that it's a "neologism", so you might not find it in a dictionary. It is existent on the website we all know, though.

Comment: To be more clear: the stanza with "fact" is not valid if your answer was correct. The stanza with "Honor" is not what you state.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I think I've got it now. If so, then you're right, I was very close indeed :-) Thinking more about the "fact" stanza (and your hint about neologism) gave me the right word. I'm still not getting the "honour" stanza though.

Comment: yepp, congrats! Before I give the tick, there's this last stanza though. I'm puzzled you haven't discovered it - don't you spaghetti?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Oh DUH! It's obvious now. I guess my mind was too much on wordplay.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

I don't have all the explanations for the clues, but could you be

> an **effect**?

I am an event,

> An effect is something that happens when you do something.

relations I set.

> "Cause and effect" is a relation between two things or concepts.

Make most to fret,

> People fear the effects of their actions? Not quite sure about this line.

threat because they get.

> Someone can get a negative effect from, say, a medication.

I sound like evil,
but actually I'm not.
Maybe as a concept,
but it is not my fault.

> These lines probably refer to a homophone of "effect," but I'm not sure what it could be. Maybe "affect," which means "to influence" perhaps using evil methods?

I sound like fact,
reality, exact.
Nothing do I have
to do with all that.

> "Effect" sounds like "a fact." Of course, a purported effect of some action might not actually occur, so we can't be sure they are real.

Honor and villainy,
beauty' n' unsightly,
a great example of me
contains of these the three.

> Don't have any ideas for this stanza, unfortunately.

As for the title,

> an effect is what will happen as a result of some action.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have it all but the right word rot13(V guvax vg fubhyq or 'pbafrdhrapr' nf va 'pnhfr naq pbafrdhrapr', fbhaqf zber ubfgvyr ohg yvgrenyyl gur fnzr nf rssrpg va guvf pbagrkg)

Comment: @Belhenix Perhaps, but then how would the middle two stanzas relate to that word? rot13(V qba'g frr nal ivnoyr ubzbcubarf sbe "pbafrdhrapr" gung pna jbex sbe rvgure bar, hayrff gurer'f n qvssrerag zrpunavfz ng cynl urer...)

Comment: @PlisNot3 rot13(znlor vg'f n fgergpu ohg vg zvtug whfg or: Va gur svefg fgnamn vg fnlf pbafrdhrapr fbhaqf yvxr n onq jbeq (guvf vf gur pbafrdhrapr bs lbhe npgvbaf!) ohg vg'f whfg cneg bs pnhfr naq rssrpg. Frpbaq fgnamn fnlf vg fbhaqf yvxr n snpg, vg pbhyq zrna n pbafrdhrapr vf frg va fgbar ohg vg'f whfg gur erfhyg bs gur pnhfr (guhf vg "unf abguvat gb qb jvgu nyy gung". Svanyyl, guveq fgnamn fnlf guerr bs gubfr 4 ner cneg bs pnhfr naq pbafrdhrapr, gubhtu V'z abg fher vs gur bqq bar vf ubabe be ornhgl (artngvir pnhfrf pna ghea fbzrbar rivy be htyl/qvfuriryrq))

Comment: As a note, I don't want to post an answer because I saw yours (the first spoiler) and it came to me, I'd consider it cheating if I posted one

Comment: Hmm, I guess we'll see what the OP has to say before we go any further, but thanks for your ideas, definitely worth consideration :)

Comment: Well, nice try. This is not the answer, not any of its synonyms though. I'll add a verse i to easy it up a bit...maybe.